# Lost Contact With 2 Former Supervisors

Tags: references

A job is asking for three current/previous supervisors as references. I have only remained in contact with one previous supervisor because they were either temporary jobs or the former supervisor changed jobs themselves. So I decided to list my former department head (supervisor's supervisor) as a reference instead. Is that a good idea? Thank you.

Comment: It isn't a bad idea. You do what you can do.

Answer (score 3):

Just give what references you can. They're just ticking boxes at this point, and there is nothing you can do if that's a deal breaker for them, which would be very rare.

Comment: This, i had many times a request for references i couldn't get together, so provided what I could, informed why I can't the rest (lost contact, person just got a child, is in middle of big raise round and ultra busy) and was never an issue.